# Estimate polynomial function

Tags: definite-integrals, estimation

Here are my difficulties, is there any method to solve or estimate the following integral?

$$\int_0^\infty\left[e^{-2λx}+(1-p) e^{-λx}-1\right]^n dx$$

where $\lambda$ and  $p$ are constants.

following is my try:

let $Z=e^{-\lambda x}$, therefor we can write:

$$f(Z)=[Z^2+(1-p)Z-1]^n $$

tailor expansion of $f(Z)$ for the first two terms is as follows:

$$f(0)=[-1]^n$$
$$f'(Z)=n[Z^2+(1-P)Z-1]^{n-1}(2Z+(1-p)) $$
$$f'(0)=n[-1]^{n-1}(1-p) $$

and the tailor expansion is as follows:

$$f(Z)\approx f(0)+f'(0)\times Z$$
$$f(x)\approx [-1]^n+n[-1]^{n-1}(1-p)\times e^{-\lambda x}$$

final estimation is :
$$\int_0^\infty\left[[-1]^n+n[-1]^{n-1}(1-p)\times e^{-\lambda x}\right]dx$$

the problem is with the $[-1]^n$

Comment: Is $n>0$?  Is $\lambda\ne0$?

Comment: yes, $n>0$ and $\lambda>0$

Comment: Since the integrand converges to a non-zero value as $x\to\infty$, your integral diverges.

Comment: @kimchilover can I argue that the original integral also diverge?

Comment: Yes, the first integral in your post diverges, unless $\lambda=0$ and $p=1$.

Comment: thanks a lot for your response